# Pulseaudio CPU load after Skype starts during session restoring

Tags: pulseaudio, skype, cpu-load

I have Kubuntu 14.04 upgraded from 12.04. If Skype starts up with system automaticly, by previous session restoring, the pulseaudio loads one core of CPU. But when I restart the Skype, everything is Ok. I face this problem only when Skype starts up with system load. Can anyone suggest me the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions the answer was to go into Skype Options, select notifications then unset the audio notification for Skype Login.
I don't know if it works on this version consistently, though I'm having some luck with it so far.